# How to import Shaka player with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, shaka

I hope my question doesn't seem silly, but I'm facing some issues when importing Shaka player in a typescript module like this:

```
import shaka from 'shaka-player/dist/shaka-player.ui';
```

In this case the compiler tells me this:

```
TS2306: File '~/dist/shaka-player.ui.d.ts' is not a module.
```

When looking at module architecture, you can obviously see in the `dist` folder contains currently the types declaration file and the js build for the module

[image]

And this is my tsconfig compiler options:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
"target": "esnext",
"module": "esnext",
"strict": true,
"jsx": "preserve",
"importHelpers": true,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"skipLibCheck": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"sourceMap": true,
"baseUrl": ".",
"allowJs": true,
"checkJs": false,
"types": [
  "webpack-env",
  "jest"
],
"paths": {
  "@/*": [
    "src/*"
  ]
},
"lib": [
  "esnext",
  "dom",
  "dom.iterable",
  "scripthost"
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Shaka is not a Typescript-native project, and the tools they are using to generate the definitions are clearly not able to do everything we need.
But there is a solution, it depends on shaka-player version.

For v3:
Create a `global.d.ts` file and declare

```
declare module 'shaka-player' {
  export = shaka;
}
```

For v4 and higher:

```
deleting all the .d.ts of the package 
rm ./node_modules/shaka-player/dist/*.d.ts
```

and then add to `global.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'shaka-player/dist/shaka-player.compiled' {
  export = shaka;
}
```

and make import:

```
 import shaka from 'shaka-player/dist/shaka-player.compiled';
```

Maybe they will add better support in future versions. But now, seems this is the only way...